# Full text search means convert everything to text?

Tags: solr

Solr uses Lucene's Full text search. Does it mean I have to convert everything to text?
For example, I have fileds like:

```
   <field name="rollno" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And a document based on these fileds,

```
 <doc>
      <field name="id">1</field>
      <field name="rollno">32</field>
      <field name="name">John Milton</field>
 </doc>
```

And I have to convert them all to text like this?

```
<copyField source="name" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="rollno" dest="text"/>
```

And my Search Handler as,

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
       <int name="rows">100</int>
       <str name="df">text</str>
     </lst>
</requestHandler>
```

Please clarify my doubt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In schema.xml file you set the [defaultSearchField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#The_Default_Search_Field) which is used to search query by default if no fieldName is setted.

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

The [df](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SearchHandler#df) parameter in the requestHandler is used for the similar purpose. It overrides the default field defined in the schema.xml file.

If you add multiple fields to this parameter using [copyField](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Copy_Fields), then you can search over all fields regardless of their types.

So, when you create your query as follows, it searches on the default field.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=searchText
```

If you want to search in specific field then you should create your query as follows. Following query will search on the rollno field.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=rollno:32
```

Answer (score 1):

You need not convert everything to text.

It depends upon the Content of the field.
You would usually use text field type for fields having more content in it.
[With text field you can a lot handling to make the content searchable](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters).
e.g.
 - Can apply lower case filter to make your searches case insensitive
 - Can apply synonyms to mark synonyms like vehicle, auto etc
 - Can apply Stemming to make words searchable by roots e.g. bank banking etc
 - And much more word delimiter for At&t and Att etc ...

You don't want usually the same anaylsis to be applied to all the fields.
e.g. you don't want the stemmer to be applied on person name or author names as it may be incorrect matches.

For fields which are integer and string you can still search on them without marking them as text if the fields are indexed.

Copy field would need to copy all your content to a field with a single field type.
If you don't want to use copy field use can use [edismax](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) parser and still search on mulitple fields.

```
<requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="defType">edismax</str>
        <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="qf">rollno name</str>
        <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    </lst> 
</requestHandler>
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this wrong. copyField doesn´t convert it to a text. It copies the value from field named name to field named text. This is normally used to have a field, which contains all of your values. This field is normally your default search field. Let me explain why this is done:

If you have your 2 field posted above, you have to declare which one is your default search field. Lets say name. If you now query the server by using normal expressions without any query syntax, than only the field name will be searched. But normally you want to have the field rollno to be searched too. To do this without any query syntax you declare another field, in this case named text. Now you copy the values from field name and field rollno to the field text and define it as default search field. If you now search for John Milton or 42 the document will be found. Hopefully this can help you a bit.